# MySQL is running out of memory every 3-7 days

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7

We're using MySQL 5.7 and have a bigger setup, where each of our customers has their own database with tables. All databases with the same setup of tables, it's just to contain them for themselves.

Our server currently has 32gb memory and we're running into the issue where MySQL takes all the memory over the span of 3 to 7 days depending on the activity.

We do know that our system do need optimizations as well and we're working on that, but it's a slow process since we can't figure out which queries are the worst.

Have attached some different informations and a picture of todays sudden memory increase

[Netdata Memory graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALMtz.png)

MySQLTuner

```
>>  MySQLTuner 1.8.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
>>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 32.4G (Tables: 45628)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 37.8M (Tables: 22)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 7
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 620 basic passwords in the list.
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 5d 13h 57m 55s (60M q [125.132 qps], 3M conn, TX: 264G, RX: 24G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 31.4G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 22.6G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 20.1G global + 17.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 20.8G (66.35% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 22.6G (72.02% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (400/60M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 29% (44/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (1/3159508)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 38% (2M temp sorts / 7M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 27618
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 52% (1M on disk / 3M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (12K created / 3M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 28% (38M hits / 137M requests)
[!!] table_definition_cache(36000) is lower than number of tables(45930) 
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (10/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (618K immediate / 618K locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 99.45% (1719946 Memory / 1729414 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/10.0M
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 85.1% (877K cached / 130K reads)
[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (927 cached / 927 writes)
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 20.0G/32.4G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 2.0G * 2/20.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 20
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 160 for 20 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (25437207254 hits/ 25437676712 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 56.94% (2658589 hits/ 4669027 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2010438 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] This server is acting as master for 1 server(s).
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] No replication setup for this server or replication not started.
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_al6`.`files`; -- can free 141 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_bo3`.`files`; -- can free 102 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_ha3`.`files`; -- can free 19 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_ju1`.`files`; -- can free 88 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_kc1`.`files`; -- can free 19 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_re41`.`files`; -- can free 33 MB
      OPTIMIZE TABLE `data_so6`.`files`; -- can free 39 MB
    Total freed space after theses OPTIMIZE TABLE : 441 Mb
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    sort_buffer_size (> 256K)
    read_rnd_buffer_size (> 256K)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    table_definition_cache(36000) > 45930 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 32.4G) if possible.
```

my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
table_definition_cache=36000
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=20
skip-external-locking
#
# * Default charset
#
character-set-server    = utf8

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
# Obsolete key_buffer option renamed to key_buffer_size by maintainer script
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
table_open_cache        = 128

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 64M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
#################################################################
# Slow query log:
slow_query_log_file      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time          = 1
slow_query_log           = 1
#################################################################
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
server-id                       = 1
binlog-format                   = mixed
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
sync_binlog                     = 1
innodb_file_per_table
log_bin                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days                = 2
max_binlog_size                 = 512M
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

# innodb_log_file_size should be set to a value greater than 10 times the largest BLOB data size used
# min. innodb_log_file_size = (10 * MEDIUM_BLOB) / innodb_log_files_in_group = (10 * 16 MB) / 2 = 80 MB;
innodb_log_file_size            = 2G

#
# * InnoDB
#

# Make sure strict mode is disabled:
sql_mode                        =IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# Make sure timestamp defaults are explicitly declared:
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
# Obsolete key_buffer option renamed to key_buffer_size by maintainer script
key_buffer_size         = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please explain why there are 45930 tables.

Comment: @RickJames  From the first sentence --- where each of our customers has their own database with tables. All databases with the same setup of tables, it's just to contain them for themselves. We do not know how many customers, yet.

Comment: @RenéDyhr    Thank You for your posted data.  Additional information request, (gathered on a busy hour), please. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; AND very helpful OS information, includes - htop OR top for most active apps, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck oh yea, I forgot that part! It's an Ubuntu server running through vmware with 8 cores(2.5ghz) and 32gb ram. If I remember correctly, it should be an ssd. I can't get you the processlist from mysql, since it would show stuff against GDPR. But it doesn't show much anyway. It's our main production server, so it runs the mysql and apache2 server. I might be able to get you some extra data when I'm in the office again monday.

Comment: @RenéDyhr      While you are gathering data on Monday, please include 
Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW MASTER STATUS;  and
C) SHOW SLAVE STATUS;   to clarify if REPLICATION usage is present  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. 
When did the OOM start bugging you - approximate date?  What approximate date was MySQL 5.7.36 implemented on your server?

Comment: Additional suggestions will be delayed until your Tuesday AM, pending receipt of additional information requested.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck A) 47148 B) File: mysql-bin.002215 Position: 372436995 C) Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event Master_Host: <ip> Master_User: <user> Master_Port: <port> Connect_Retry: 60 Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002215 Read_Master_Log_Pos: 373131963 Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.234588 Relay_Log_Pos: 373130908 Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002215 Slave_IO_Running: Yes Slave_SQL_Running: Yes. And we updated to MySQL 5.7.36 2021-10-20 and it's before that we got issues

Answer (score 0):

Just ONE primary cause of OOM.

```
com_savepoint counted 3,882 during your 1.1 days of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS

com_release_savepoint counted 0 releases.
```

Net result is each failure to release savepoint when it is no longer needed equals resources not released with eventual OOM.  Find mysql savepoint tutorial and look at closely, please.

There are many more configuration needs.  In another answer by your Monday AM, I will give you aditional suggestions to settle down your table open thrashing that is killing performance.  View profile for contact info, please.

Comment: @Rene Dyhr     This observation could be wrong.  Still digging deeper.  Thanks, Wilson

Comment: @Rene Dyhr     Most of the instances I have reviewed are attempting to RELEASE SAVEPOINT namedsavepoint with their unit of work.  Many have exact matches between com_savepoint and com_release_savepoint and are trouble free.  You had 1 com_release_savepoint in your 1.1 day SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider to reduce table_open thrashing ONLY situation.

OS per your ulimit -a report has Open Files limit of 1024
From your OS Command prompt,
ulimit -n 500000 and press Enter will enable dynamic limit of Open Files to support MySQL and other apps when needed.  In MySQL alone, your system  added ~ 1,500 tables in less than a week to new MySQL table/file count of 47,148 today.

To make this persistent across OS stop/start, follow this URL for a guide, please,
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/
your specifics may be slightly different.  Do apply 500,000 as this guide was
trying to accomplish.  Try to get this persistent in a controlled environment in the next few days.  If not, just use ulimit -n 500000 to dynamically enable the higher limit before starting MySQL after uncontrolled OOM crash.  Use ulimit -a anytime when in doubt to determine current Open Files limit.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf

```
table_open_cache=120000  # from 128 to reduce opened_tables RPS of 218
innodb_open_files=120000  # from 300 - this should always be = table_open_cache
table_definition_cache=75000  # from 36000 for more than table_count 
        to reduce opened_table_definitions RPS of 148
open_files_limit=256000  # from 5000 - to reduce opened_files RPS of 226
```

These changes include Static Global Variables and will require MySQL start/stop.

View profile for contact info, if needed.  Many more performance tuning opportunities exist for your application.  We would like to assist.

Comment: Sound amazing, we will start out trying these settings to see what difference it makes. Though a question about the table_open thrashing you're talking about. How would that effect memory consumption. By increasing, would it not also increase memory footprint?

Comment: Your Netdata Memory Graph clearly documents intense memory consumption for a few hours.  When you are opening more than 200 tables per second for more than 24 hours, expect anything to go wrong/sideways.  Get your ulimit -a increased BEFORE changing any MySQL configuration.  Dynamic ulimit -n 500000 will be fine, Then make all changes to my.cnf before stop/start, please.

Comment: PS, in the future, when considering upgrade of any version, determine how many months the version you are considering has been GA.  Use google search for 'mysql 5.7.36 changelog' to quickly determine WHEN the version to be considered became GA.  If the version has not been GA for 3 months, unless you are having a specific problem that has been addressed, give other people the opportunity to detect and report problems with the new version.  Unless you have time to dedicate to 'problem detection and reporting and praying for quick resolution' to correct your 'production system' that is dead.

Comment: For your last question, yes the footprint will grow about no more than 4 bytes per supported table/file. So, open_file_limit (256,000 * 4) =1Meg.  Not much for a 32G server,

Comment: We have tested the config changes on a development server and we can see that one of our scripts that runs every 10 minutes and looping through all databases and selecting a few a row on a indexed table gives us a memory bump. It does that every single time it runs. Shouldn't it stop at some point at least?

Comment: @RenéDyhr Please post your ERROR LOG for 2 minutes before start of script and 2 minutes after start of script.  Post the script that is called every 10 minutes, please. History usually repeats unless action is taken to intervene and enable whatever is failing to be successful.  View profile and make contact, please.

Comment: We have figured out that table_open_cache_instances is default set to 16 and MySQL recommends 8 or 16 if you got 16 or more cores. After changing that to 4 on our development server with 2 cores, it seems we can cap it more. Do you know about this setting and what it does and what issues it can give?

Comment: My research in the past concluded this value should be NO MORE than number of CORES.  table_open_cache_instances reduces contention when open activity is substantial - which it is EVERY 10 minutes in your instance.  It would be interesting to see from your TEST server TEXT results of - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count.  Thanks

Comment: @RenéDyhr An excellent URL that describes WHAT this variable controls.  https://severalnines.com/database-blog/mysql-performance-cheat-sheet   Search for table_open_cache_instances within the article, please.